# Resharper run unit test from specified folder but missing application configuration file

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, resharper

When I run a unit test from a specified folder, I realized that the application configuration file is not used as it is simply not there. How is this supposed to work? Should the application configuration file be copied by Resharper (which means I might have found a bug), or should I copy the file there with a post-build event or something like that? What would be a clean solution for this?

I have confirmed that there really is no application configuration file loaded with [Fuslogvw.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I am using Resharper 9.0.

**EDIT**

I do not run the unit test from it's build folder but from another *specified folder* which is the build folder of another project that does reference the project running the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you've got your config file saved as `app.config` under the unit test project in visual studio.

Right click that file, and select `Properties`. In the properties window, you'll see an option **Copy to Output Directory** - change it's value to **Copy always**.

From now on, a new version of your config file will be written to the output directory each time you build your project.

**Update:** Place the config-file in your main project, if that makes things easier; that should then be written to your build-folder when you build the main project.

Remember you can always create different versions of a config file, e.g. for test and production, and use the former while running your unit tests.

Comment: See my edit. Maybe we have a strange setup (the reason for it is reducing build time in development as copying around dll s is very expensive).

Comment: @Sjoerd2228888 Can you place the config file in the main project then? (Updated my answer).